# log4j2 auto-initialization disable is not working with isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled <context-parm>

Tags: log4j2, servlet-4

emphasized textI'm working on migration of log4j version from 1.2.17 to Log4j2 , as part of migration I have chosen bridge option
as per the [guideliness](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/migration.html)  , while migrating  log4j.xml to log4j2.xml for RollingFile we are having properties to substitute for file creation as below

```
     <RollingFile name="file"
        fileName="${log.directory}server.log.${log.id}server.log"
        filePattern="${log.directory}server.log.${log.id}server.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%t %X{RequestId} %X{CallerId}) [%c{1}] %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5000 KB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>
```

And these variables resolved after execution of one of custom **(com.MyCustomListener)** written during startup , This flow is working as expected with log4j 1.2.17 .
With log4j2 as per the  [Specification](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) provided by apache auto-initialization of log4j2 happens during server startup automatically , due to this auto-initialization at the being of server startup my listener which resolves variables is executing after initialization of log4j as a result variables are not resolving, I am using **servlet version 4.0**
I tried to disable auto-initialization by adding below  beginning of my web.xml

```
            <context-param>
                <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </context-param>
```

But still this is not helping me ,  log4j2 initialization is happening before my  execution
I want my  execution first before log4j2 initialization.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
                id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
                
                <display-name>MyApplication</display-name>
                
                 <listener>
                    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
                </listener>
             
                <filter>
                    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
                    <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
                </filter>
                <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
                    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
                    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
                    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
                </filter-mapping>
                
                <context-param>
                  <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
                  <param-value>true</param-value>
                </context-param>

                <!-- init properties shared by entire application -->
                <context-param>
                    <param-name>earDeploymentDescriptorPath</param-name>
                    <param-value>application.xml</param-value>
                </context-param>
                <listener>
                    <listener-class>com.MyCustomListener</listener-class>
                </listener>
                
                <!-- bootstrap Log4j -->
                <!-- Log4j refresh interval -->
                <context-param>
                    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
                    <param-value>60000</param-value>
                </context-param>
                <context-param>
                    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
                    <param-value>false</param-value>
                </context-param>
                
                <!-- welcome file list-->
                <welcome-file-list>
                    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
                </welcome-file-list>
                
            </web-app>
```

I have enabled TRACE logs for log4j2 , From the logs I have observed that log4j is initializing before my custom listener(com.MyCustomListener)

*2021-05-19 05:11:49,314 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,314 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2021-05-19 05:11:49,314 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,314 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2021-05-19 05:11:49,330 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,330 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%t) [%c{1}] %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(vfs:/C:/SL3/CPS_EMR_ALL/jboss/standalone/deployments/PracticeEAR.ear/lib/Practice.jar/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2021-05-19 05:11:49,330 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,330 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 46 plugins
2021-05-19 05:11:49,330 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,330 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2021-05-19 05:11:49,345 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,345 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%t) [%c{1}] %m%n), name="console", Configuration(vfs:/C:/SL3/CPS_EMR_ALL/jboss/standalone/deployments/PracticeEAR.ear/lib/Practice.jar/log4j2.xml), Filter=null, ={})
2021-05-19 05:11:49,345 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,345 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2021-05-19 05:11:49,345 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,345 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2021-05-19 05:11:49,345 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19 05:11:49,345 ServerService Thread Pool -- 71 DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%t %X{RequestId} %X{CallerId}) [%c{1}] %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(vfs:/C:/SL3/CPS_EMR_ALL/jboss/standalone/deployments/PracticeEAR.ear/lib/Practice.jar/log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2021-05-19 05:11:49,580 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19T05:11:49,580 INFO (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) [MyCustomListner] ********************** Entry to MyCustomListner class **********************
2021-05-19 05:11:49,611 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) 2021-05-19T05:11:49,611 ERROR (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) [MyCustomListner] ********************** Exit from MyCustomListner class ***********************

Your help is apricated

Comment: Just to make this a great question, one that's easy to answer (by someone other than myself who is familiar with your toolset), try including the error messages that lead you to believe the problem you're facing is that some (which?) variables aren't initialized.  If your custom action is being run "too soon", maybe your question is more like how to execute it later in the flow.

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same issue.